# QGIS Bonn - Trying to use query builder to exclude multiple test strings

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am entering `"textString" != 'Hilltop' OR "textString" != 'Amberley'` in to the Provider specific filter expression in order to EXCLUDE these two names in OS Cartographic text. The query correctly shows 1353 rows, but these no longer show on my OS map. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To exclude those terms you need an AND not an OR as negatives reverse the logic operations. So your test is always true because `textString` can't equal Hilltop and Amberley at the same time.

So either:

```
textString" != 'Hilltop' AND "textString" != 'Amberley'
```

or:

```
NOT(textString" = 'Hilltop' OR "textString" = 'Amberley')
```

Comment: Thanks ever so much for pointing out what I was` doing wrong. Sadly after leaving school 60 years ago, I seem to have forgotten my logic ...

Comment: No problem, it's an error I make myself often, and I've seen highly paid senior devs screw it up every time too. please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark

Comment: I have tried both of your suggestions, but in both cases whilst I get confirmation that my query has returned 1353 entries, (which I believe is correct), NONE of them are visible. I feel therefore that I am missing a trick within QGIS that is thus preventing the displaying of the remaining items. Have you any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: we'd need to see more of your set up to be sure. Does it display labels with out the filter?

Comment: In desperation I have gone back to using QGIS 2.18.10, Las Palmas. All the queries work PERFECTLY, but same queries in Version 3.0 (Girona) or 3.2.3 (Bonn) still return reasonable result counts, but will not display. There must be some setting or option in QGIS v3 and above that I am missing. Anyone help please?

Comment: It is fine either with no filter, or with just a single textstring defined. Problem only happens with QGIS v3 when I add a second argument. As I say, the item count changes logically to reduce the number of items left, but it just won;t show them to me on the map! Going back to 2.18, everything works perfectly